# Update policy most-recent feed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Does anyone know wether the (german or any other langauge specific) "Most recent" Feed for a Category ("News & Politics") updates in realtime or how to get the most-recent videos in this category? It seems like it does not include all videos uploaded in this category...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't provide a true "fire hose" feed for newly updated videos in given categories. The "most recent" feed is updated on a delayed basis, and the actual interval at which it's updated varies.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!Is there any chance to get a firehose access for scientific purposes?

Comment: But are the country specific feeds still updated? And how do they mirror the most viewed clips as shown in the youtube.com/charts page?